# Meaning of Maven dependency scopes "compile" vs. "runtime"

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, pom.xml

From the viewpoint of a Gradle java library author, I understand that a dependency specified in the `implementation` configuration will be marked with the `runtime` scope in the resulting POM file that gets published (using the `maven-publish` Gradle plugin). This makes sense, as *anyone consuming my published library* doesn't need the dependency for compilation (it is an internal dependency), but instead only for runtime. If I specify a dependency in the `api` configuration, it will be marked with the `compile` scope in the resulting POM file, which again makes sense, as *anyone consuming my library* needs this for compilation (and runtime).

This makes me believe that the meaning of the Maven dependency scope is **relative to anyone consuming the component, and not relative to the component itself**. Consider a published Maven library (containing Java class files) a dependency marked with `compile` should mean:

> If you compile against me, then use this dependency on the compilation classpath too!

However, according to the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope), it seems that it means:

> I was compiled with that dependency on my compilation classpath, and if you want to compile me again, do the same!

If this were true, then one could not distinguish between API-dependencies and implementation-dependencies like Gradle does. Also, it would only make sense if the published component actually contains the sources, not only the class files.

Did Gradle actually "misuse" the meaning of these scopes to make some improvements, or did I fundamentally misunderstand something?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to find some common sense in software which was designed over 15 years ago, that time nobody was ever thinking about spring-boot, microservices, native images, etc... Splitting dependencies onto API and Implementation makes sense for local projects only, as soon as you are going to publish it, maven's legacy devaluates all possible advantages of such approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle cleverly "misuses" the scopes.

Maven has the design flaw that the build POM is published 1:1 as consumer POM (this will change with the upcoming Maven 4.x). So Maven does not have the chance to use something for compilation in the project, but for runtime when consumed by another project (at least not without applying tricks). The Maven docs therefore do not discuss the possibility of "implementation/api".

Comment: what you are talking about (consumer poms) is planned in maven 5: https://www.javaadvent.com/2021/12/from-maven-3-to-maven-5.html (read: will never happen), and has nothing in common with the actual Q: TC is asking about publishing maven artifacts.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov The first steps of decoupling build POM and consumer POM are done in Maven 4.x, for which there is already an alpha version available. Total decoupling will probably take much longer. And furthermore, it answers the question in the sense that it explains why Maven does not have "compile in my project, runtime in other projects" like Gradle has.